# Different pronunciation for words starting with en- ( /ɪn/, /en/ and /ɪˈ/ )

Tags: pronunciation

Are there any guides to know when to pronounce as /ɪn/, /en/ and /ɪˈ/?

For e.g. enable, entertain, enforce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stress often affects vowels in English

To be clear, the symbol ˈ is usually used to mark a syllable break before a primary-stressed syllable. The word *enable* could be pronounced as /ɪˈneɪbl̩/, but the /ɪ/ in this transcription doesn't correspond to *en-,* only to the first letter, E. The N is pronounced as /n/, it's just moved to the start of the following syllable because it comes before a vowel (spelled as A and pronounced as /eɪ/ here).

The vowel in *en-* is pronounced as /ɪ/ only in words that have no stress on the first syllable. There are many *en-* words of this type.

In the less common situation where the first syllable has any kind of stress (either primary stress, marked with `ˈ`, or secondary stress, marked with `ˌ`), the vowel will not be /ɪ/.

As a stressed syllable, *en-* is regularly pronounced with the vowel /ɛ/ (also transcribed /e/, and called "short e": this is the vowel found in the word *pen*). The word *entertain* has primary stress on the third syllable, and secondary stress on the first syllable, so the first syllable has /ɛ/. It is pronounced as /ˌɛntr̩ˈteɪn/.

But *en-* also has an irregular pronunciation with a third vowel quality. Ssome words spelled with *en-* are pronounced with /ɑn/ in imitation of the French vowel used in words spelled with *en.* This irregular pronunciation of *en-* is possible in stressed syllables (as in *ˈenvelope*) and also in syllables that can be seen as unstressed (such as in *enˈsemble*).

### "Flowchart" of questions for words starting with *en-*

Here's a set of questions that could be used like a flowchart (with examples of specific words):

Is the E of *en-* in a stressed syllable?

- Yes:

  - Pronounce it as /ɛn/: *ˌenterˈtain, ˈengine, ˈenvy, ˈenemy*
  - OR Pronounce it as /ɛn/ or /ɑn/: *ˈenvelope*
  - OR Pronounce it as /ɑn/: *ˌentrepreˈneur*
- No: Is the N before a consonant?

  - Yes: Pronounce the *en-* as /ɪn/.

    *enˈcamp, enˈcapsulate, enˈcircle, enˈclose, enˈcompass, enˈcourage, enˈcrypt, enˈcumber, enˈdanger, enˈdear, enˈdeavor, enˈdorse, enˈdow, enˈdure, enforce, engage, engulf, enhance, enjoy, enˈlarge, enˈlighten, enˈlist, enˈliven, enˈmesh, enˈrage, enˈrich, enˈsconce, enˈslave, enˈsnare, enˈsue, enˈtangle, enˈthral(l), enˈtice, enˈtitle, enˈtomb, enˈtrap, enˈtreat, enˈtreaty, enˈtrench, enˈvision*
  - No: Pronounce the *en-* as /ɪˈn/, where the second syllable starts with /n/.

    *eˈnable, eˈnact, eˈnamo(u)r*
  - OR Pronounce the *en-* as /ɑn/.

### Variation in unstressed syllables

Some American English speakers tend to replace /ɪ/ in fully unstressed syllables with /ə/. This has been called the "weak vowel merger". A speaker with this merger might pronounce *enable* as /əˈneɪbl̩/, and *enforce* as /ənˈfors/.

Some speakers use the unreduced vowel [ɛ] even when *en-* is an unstressed syllable, which would cause *enable* to be pronounced as /ɛˈneɪbl̩/, and *enforce* as /ɛnˈfors/.

You can see a similar discussion about variability in the pronunciation of words starting with *ex-* in the answers to this ELU question: [Is there a rule for the correct pronunciation of words starting with “ex”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54489)